# IE10 on Windows 7, where is localStorage stored in the file system?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10, local-storage

I'm looking for the location in the file system for IE10's localStorage in Windows 7.

Interestingly, there are subdirectories for the web domains that have localStorage objects at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\DOMStorage (hat tip to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12512348/286599).  I'm not sure how this relates...

EDIT: I hooked up Process Monitor, filtered output by iexplore.exe, and manually added, read and removed a localStorage object at the console, and indeed IE was messing around with an XML file in one of the directories I mentioned above, eg `WriteFile | C:\Users\Standard User\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore\ODWNKVYX\anothertrick[1].xml`.

RE-EDIT: Initially, I didn't see that DOMStore folder in explorer / DOS but realized I hadn't unchecked the "Hide System Files" setting for this user account.

Comment: FWIW: I have IE11 on Windows 7, and the DOMStore folder exists and I can see it/get into it.

Comment: Stupidity! - didn't untick "Hide System Files" for this user.  @techie007, feel free to drop an answer in (it's just `%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStorage\`) or I will eventually.